# How can I set the display resolution to 800x480?

Tags: 12.04, display, resolution, screen

I have just installed Ubuntu 12.04 and I have a problem with it. My mini-laptop has a display resolution of 800x480, however Ubuntu seems to support only a resolution of 800x600.

I have looked for a solution, but I have found nothing which works.

So, how can I set the display resolution to 800x480?

---

hey, hola a todos!

Acabo de instalar Ubuntu 12.04 y en verdad me gusta mucho. pero aunque me guste bastante, tengo un pequeño gran problema, LA RESOLUCION DE MI PANTALLA!!!

mi mini-laptop tiene una resolución de 800x480, pero Ubuntu viene con una por defecto de 800x600. en verdad me gustaria que me pudieran ayudar. llevo rato buscando una solucion, pero NADA!!!

espero que me puedan ayudar!!! gracias de antemano!!! SALUDOS

Comment: We'd probably need a bit more info to be able to help you. Can you provide the exact model number? video card? It's hard to help you when all we have to go from is that the resolution is wrong in your 'mini-laptop'. PS. you're english is just fine.

Comment: Hi Oswaldo, can you tell me if your laptop has an Intel, Nvidia or Ati video card?. Hola Oswaldo, bienvenido a este mundo, me podrias decir si tu laptop usa una tarjeta de video Intel, Ati o Nvidia?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did when my resolution was wacky.

Reboot. Al empezar, escoja recovery mode y failsafe graphics mode. Then an option comes up about resetting your graphics settings. Do that. Reset to default and reboot de nuevo.

Si no me explico claramente (sé que no), hágame cualquier pregunta que tenga.

Buena suerte.

Edit: Your English is very good. But I would have said "nothing works..."
Edit again: "nothing which works" is fine but "nothing **that** works" is better.

Comment: The distinction between 'that' and 'which' is apparently treated as an undisputed fact to those who pontificate about grammar. (Who knew?) But I think [**more pragmatic opinions are less rigid**](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/78). BTW & just FWIW, I used "nothing that/which works" over "nothing works" in my edit because I felt the latter implied that no solution was possible. Whereas "nothing that works" I felt implies a solution exists and it just has not been discovered yet. cc: @Oswaldo